# Will there be any performance difference in professional edition from developer edition?

Tags: professional-edition, enterprise, developer-edition, unlimited

I have been working on a VF page (developer org) where it shows some 1000 records and it is taking around 14 secs to show up the complete data even after using pagination. So, i had a doubt will there be any performance issue in other editions also.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to work out where the problem is:

- is the server-side query slow (perhaps could be optimised by using different where clause or asking Salesforce support to add an index)
- is the server-side HTML generation slow (e.g. is the code looping over many records before it gets to the ones you want)
- is it the time to transmit the data over the internet (if so then transmit less data e.g. 100 per page not 1000 per page)
- is it the time it takes the browser to render the HTML (if so then transmit less data e.g. 100 per page not 1000 per page)

Then you can work on the actual problem.

Visualforce works well for many types of problem but can't stretch to solving every problem. You should read [Visualforce Performance: Best
Practices](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_visualforce_best_practices.pdf).

Once you fully understand the problem, sometimes the only solution is to go back to your customer and explain that their requirements can't be met without the page being slow and discuss alternatives with them.

When you move code from a development org (that usually has a small number of records) to a production org that has a large number of records performance usually becomes a bigger not smaller problem.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it is not going to make any difference when you change instances, as it practically depends on

1. Your Internet Connection
2. Distance from nearest SF Data Centre
3. Number of records you are processing in your queries
4. Number of Total records in your org.

If your are displaying a selective set of records on the page and only need pagination, I would recommend to go for Client side pagination.

Also if you are using standard actionMethods to retrieve records, replace them with JS Remoting.